# NgfileUpload - How to apply validation one each file while sending them all in one request

Tags: javascript, ng-file-upload

This is an already made fiddle for multiple file in one request [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/huhjo9jm/5/). Now I want to have a validation in which no file should be greater than `1MB` . How can I do this ? How can I through error on each file. ?

Comment: Strictly from a user point of view, they won't like being blocked by your site this way. If my mom gets blocked by a message saying "Images max 1MB", she has no idea what a MB is, let alone reduce an image weight. So she'll have no other choice but leave your site. You should handle that by silently resizing the image, either client-side (canvas) or server-side.

Comment: I believe there is a `size` property on every uploaded `File` object. Did you try using it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through each of the files and check their size and then show whatever error you want. I simply set the error message here but you can do something else.

```
//inject angular file upload directives and services.
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
    $scope.uploadFiles = function (files) {
        $scope.files = files;
        if (files && files.length) {
            if (!files.every(function(file) {
              return file.size < 1;
            })) {
               return $scope.errorMsg = 'File size too big';
            };
            Upload.upload({
                url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
                data: {
                    files: files
                }
            }).then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.result = response.data;
                });
            }, function (response) {
                if (response.status > 0) {
                    $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
                }
            }, function (evt) {
                $scope.progress = 
                    Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/huhjo9jm/756/